# Node fs can't access static files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to access publicly-accessible static files (both .png and .ttf) through a function in Node. The files exist, and can be accessed through the browser using the URL. For example, accessing

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/images/thefile.png
```

resolves the image in a browser.

However, if I try to test the file with fs.stat (pulled from elsewhere on StackOverflow):

```
fs.stat(testPath, function(err, stat) {
    if(err == null) {
        console.log('File exists');
    } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
    }
});
```

it results in:

```
Error:  { [Error: ENOENT, stat 'http://localhost:9000/assets/images/thefile.png']
errno: 34,
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'http://localhost:9000/assets/images/thefile.png' }
```

Everything else I'm finding relates to not being able to access static files through the browser, but not Node itself trying to access them. I'm hoping someone might know what I'm missing.

Comment: You cannot access using http://localhost.... when you are using fs. You should give the path of the file.

Comment: The `fs` module is intended for working with files on a local [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). You can use [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to request files from a web server by URL.

Comment: @NikhilBaliga That makes sense. I was able to do some trial and error and work out the right relative path to use. One more question, though: would a relative path like "./dist/public/assets/" continue to work when pushed to Heroku? I don't fully understand how Heroku's handling the files yet.